# Problems integrating PayPal IPN in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here I am, having difficulties trying to integrate PayPal IPN in my PHP code. After looking for some tutorial on the net I found a few and went for this one: http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration. It got me started, but when coming to real coding, things aren't that easy. Namely the function Payments.php is giving me trouble.

I am having some problem here in the code:

```
// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])) {
    ......
} else {
    //Database Connection
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);
    ......
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);

        $totalRes = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            $totalRes .= $res;

            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                ......
            } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                ......
            }
            ......
        }

        mail('myMail@abc.com','Report: PayPay-PHP-IPN', "Total RESPONSE: $totalRes");
    }

    fclose ($fp);
}
```

I have added the $totalRes variable to the original code, in order to find out what is going on.

I get the following in my mail when I run the code above:

Total RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2016 02:31:55 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
X-Cnection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

400 Bad Request

## Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

And no update is made to my database.

Obviously things are not happening as they should. Ideally I should get something telling me that my product was purchased and have a trace in the database.

What is the problem here? And how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance for any relevant tip.

Comment: That wouldn't have anything to do with IPN at that point because the payment hasn't taken place yet.  IPN is a post-transaction processor.  Can you post a sample of the full redirect string that gets used instead of the code sample?  Seems maybe you aren't getting what you expect out of $querystring..??

Comment: @Andrew I have edited the question, hoping this provides an answer to your question. I am not very confident about the way I build $querystring.

Comment: @Andrew. Puzzled by your comment, I went and made some changes in my code. Thanks to you, I discovered some issues an made a big step forward. My problem is now at a different stage, I reedited my question to reflect that.